# Multi-boot problem resolution

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Can someone here help me resolve a problem I just created?  I had a dual boot system working fine with hopes of going on to a multi-boot system between 4 O/S's.  I have Windows7 and Ubuntu 16.10 in separate partitions.  The first partition was left empty intentionally. I installed Qubes in the first partition to learn during the install process that it doesn't have native support for dual boot or multi-boot options.  My problem now is that I need help to update / repair the master boot record and install grub so that my computer will boot between 3 operating systems.  Having run a repair disk utility that produced boot status information it looks like the following: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23901037

What are the steps I need to take to have access to all operating systems on this machine?

Comment: Know nothing about Qubes. But Windows only boots from a primary NTFS partition with the boot flag. You have Windows in a logical partition and are now missing some boot files. Did you erase the boot partition? Better not to use a separate /boot partition unless full drive LVM. It just adds complication especially with multiple installs as you cannot share a /boot. Also FAT32 is not recommended for larger partitions, it cannot store any file over 4GB and does not have a journal. Did you run Boot-repair's suggested fix of reinstalling grub to MBR.

Comment: Oh yes... I made the mistake of sharing `/boot` once. That's enough confusion and trouble for a whole weekend.

Comment: Yes, I did run Boot-repair's suggested fix to no avail.  What I am attempting to do now after wiping out Qubes, is create a 200 /boot partition, install Grub2 and install Qubes in a partition closer to the rear of the drive.

Comment: I ran Boot-repair again and took the suggested fix.  Now when booting I arrive at the prompt of no operating system.   I was getting a grub rescue>  prompt.  Now it seems I need to transfer an OS to my hard drive to continue working back to the dual boot options I started with.

Comment: Not sure if Ubuntu works or works well with ext2, standard now is ext4 format. You really do not need a separate grub partition. Now with grub2 you can easily multi-boot. But have to make sure grub2 is the one in the MBR and from your main working install. Windows still only boots from primary NTFS partition with boot flag. Now with primary NTFS partition, you may be able to move boot flag to it and run a full set of Windows repairs. Still better to have Windows main partition as primary.