# Multi-boot screwup

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I need help getting my system to boot normally again. I am usnig it fo this post to prove that it does work normally once running. The situation is it once was a dual boot system working fine using Ubuntu 16.10 and Windows7. I installed a 3 Linux OS to read during the installation process there was no support for dual booting. Once the install had completed I was left with only that Linux OS and no access to my original dual booting OS's. After much thought and struggle I ran GParted, formatted that (1st) partition, resized it removing 200 mb for a boot partition at the beginning of the drive and rebooted. --- I got a Grub Rescue> prompt. That is where am currently challenged to overcome. I can boot my system using a Super Grub Disk. -- I want to have a boot partition with Grub in it that will eventually allow me to boot between 4 Operating Systems. One of the OS's is Qubes (the offending animal) but it will not reside in the first partition.

Any help here with this adventuresome challenge?

Comment: With some luck all you need is to run `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu but it may not find Qubes. What I think happened is you had Windows 10 and Ubuntu correctly installed in UEFI mode, then you installed Qubes in legacy, a requirement for R3.0 or earlier: https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/system-requirements/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-boot problem resolution](http://askubuntu.com/questions/878458/multi-boot-problem-resolution)

Comment: Please edit your original question and add more information to it instead of reposting the same question.